# How to reduce order of this ODE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I want to reduce this ODE to lower order but I am confused in some steps. Can someone comment?

$$
AB\frac{d^3u}{dz^3}+C(D-z)\frac{du}{dz}=0, \,\, 0<z<L 
$$
$A,B,C,D,L$ are constants, all greater than zero.

I want to convert 3rd order ODE to 2nd order. So, I make following substitutions:

$$
x=D-z \implies z=D-x\\ 
y(x)=u'(z)=\frac{du}{dz} \\
\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{d}{dx} \bigg(\frac{du}{dz} \bigg)=\frac{d}{dx} \bigg ( \frac{du}{dx} \frac{dx}{dz} \bigg) = \frac{d}{dx} \bigg(- \frac{du}{dx} \bigg)
$$
This is not working. Any ideas how should I go on substitution?

Comment: I don't know why you want substitute $D-z$ with something else, but use $y(x) = \frac{du}{dz}$ substitution first. This will nicely reduce the order of ODE.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\dfrac{du}{dz}=v$ ,

Then $\dfrac{d^3u}{dz^3}=\dfrac{d^2v}{dz^2}$

$\therefore AB\dfrac{d^2v}{dz^2}+C(D-z)v=0$